# How to make change to frame animate from the top in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make an "expandable" view that when tapped, expands the frame downward. I created a state variable `isExpanded` to toggle when the view is tapped. Then, I added a `.frame` modifier that sets the height to 180 when expanded and 80 when not. The issue is that when the frame expands, it does so from the middle in a very buggy-looking and ugly manner. I'd like it to expand from the top, as if it were dropping down. Here's the code:

```
@State private var isExpanded: Bool = false

ZStack {
    VStack {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }

    HStack {
        Text("test")

        Spacer()

        // this image acts like a "dropdown" toggle
        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
            .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue Medium", size: 16))
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.isExpanded ? -90 : 0))
    }
}
.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation(.spring()) {
        self.isExpanded.toggle()
    }
}
.frame(maxHeight: isExpanded ? 180 : 80)
```

Comment: For the outer `ZStack`, you can add a top alignment like `ZStack(alignment: .top){ ... }`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep unfortunately I believe that does not work.